# How do I exclude a column in a "ThenInclude" object in Entity Framework select query

Tags: entity-framework, select

I am doing a complex Entity Framework select query and I want to exclude one specific column in an object that is "ThenIncluded".

I tried to find a solution in StackOverflow, but no-one really fits my complex query.

Here is the query:

```
// topLevelId is given when we get here
await this.Context.TopLevel
                .Include(c1 => c1.Child1)
                .Include(c2 => c2.Child2)
                .Include(c3 => c3.Child3)
                .Include(c4 => c4.Child4).ThenInclude(gc1 => gc1.GrandChild1)
                .Include(c4 => c4.Child4).ThenInclude(gc2 => gc2.GrandChild2)
                .Include(c4 => c4.Child4).ThenInclude(gc3 => gc3.GrandChild3)
                .FirstAsync(tl => tl.TopLevelId == topLevelId);
```

The "ThenIncluded" object I need to exclude a column from is **GrandChild1**, which is of this type:

```
public partial class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        this.MyType = new HashSet<MyType>();
    }

    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyType> MyType { get; set; }
}
```

And the column I want to exclude is **Data** (a byte array).

NB: I need that column in other queries and updates, so I cannot ignore the column from my EF model.

Comment: you'll have to .Select() the other properties you need, there's no specific exclusion method

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but how do I do that in a ThenIncluded object?
I have seen the Select() in simple examples, but nothing with Include/ThenInclude...

Comment: you can't do that in Include, you'll have to do it afterwards in the navigation properties

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. How would that Select afterwards look like?

Comment: Look at [Table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting).

Comment: @GertArnold: Thanks for the advice. I did think about a new class for the reduced object. But in my case, it means that I also need new classes for its parents (Child4 and TopLevel)?

Comment: It's not really clear from your question, but from what I can see you only need to split `Document`.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, let me clarify! 
Document is a property in the type of GrandChild1.
If I were to split the Document class to another, say DocumentReduced, I would also have to create a new type for GrandChild1.
(And then the same for its parent TopLevel.)

Comment: It would really help if you could show the class models. For one, `Document` is not a *column* in another class, it is a class itself that you can `Include` if needed. So I don't understand the way you explain it here.

Comment: I don't think I said Document is a column. 
The core of the problem here is that I have a complex data hierarchy, so splitting out a DocumentReduce means splitting out many other related classes.

Anyway, I will solve this by not including the Data byte array in the EF class, and handle the byte array outside EF. Thanks for pointing me to the table splitting, it was interesting to see what EF can and can't do.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your consumer needs, you use `.Select()` to tell EF what data you want to pull. This can be relational like your data model, or you can flatten the data from the hierarchy down into a simpler structure.

For instance, given:

```
await this.Context.TopLevel
                .Include(c1 => c1.Child1).ThenInclude(gc1 => gc1.GrandChild1)
                .FirstAsync(tl => tl.TopLevelId == topLevelId);
```

Assuming GrandChild1 is the Document with the byte array.

```
public class TopLevelViewModel
{
   public int TopLevelId { get; set; }
   public int Child1Id { get; set; }
   public string DocumentName { get; set; }
   public string FileName { get; set; }
}

await this.Context.TopLevel
    .Select(x => new TopLevelViewModel
    {
        TopLevelId = x.TopLevelId,
        Child1Id = x.Child1.Child1Id,
        DocumentName = x.Child1.Grandchild1.DocumentName,
        FileName = x.Child1.GrandChild1.FileName
    }).SingleAsync(x => x.TopLevelId = topLevelId);
```

If the children represent a 1-to-many collection then you can define a ChildViewModel with their relevant document details:

```
public class TopLevelViewModel
{
   public int TopLevelId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Child1ViewModel> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child1ViewModel>();
}
public class Child1ViewModel
{
   public int Child1Id { get; set; }
   public string DocumentName { get; set; }
   public string FileName { get; set; }
}

await this.Context.TopLevel
    .Select(x => new TopLevelViewModel
    {
        TopLevelId = x.TopLevelId,
        Children = x.Child1s.Select( c => new Child1ViewModel
        {
            Child1Id = c.Child1Id,
            DocumentName = c.Grandchild1.DocumentName,
            FileName = c.GrandChild1.FileName
        }).ToList()
    }).SingleAsync(x => x.TopLevelId = topLevelId);
```

You can structure the relationships and data to pull back as you like. The advantages are that you only pull back the data fields you need which can reduce the payload size to improve performance, leverage indexes on the database, and keep from revealing too much about your data structure to the consumer.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! So the Select eliminates the need for Include/ThenInclude? And: what if I need to take the complete other children (it's only the Grandchild1 I need to "reduce").

Comment: Yes, /w Select you don't need Includes. Regarding taking complete other records it really depends on what you use them for. If it's internal code logic then you can use Select to select the entities as-is. However if it is to pass outside the scope of the DbContext such as to return to a view, then I recommend composing view models. Automapper can help convert entities to ViewModels within a query via `ProjectTo<TViewModel>` in place of `Select`. For returning data, the less you select, the better the overall performance can be.

Comment: Does EF recognize that Automapper only needs some properties of the returned entities for conversion to the viewmodel, and project the other columns away?

Comment: ProjectTo will translate the requested fields from the DTO/ViewModel according to the mapping setup. It works with EF's `IQueryable` behaviour So if the view model only has some of the fields, it will effectively build the Select statement for just those fields for you. When working with Select and ProjectTo I recommend using a Profiler like ExpressProfiler to listen in on the database and capture the SQL being generated to verify that your queries are only pulling the fields expected. It also helps detect performance issues like unexpected lazy loads.

Comment: @StevePy: Thanks, I'll try it out on Monday.

Comment: Ok, this became complicated (due to my complex hierarchy).
I will solve this by not including the Data byte array in the EF class, and handle the byte array outside EF.
But thanks!